# How should I achieve continuous write operation via rdma WRITE

Tags: rdma

I am a novice in learning rdma. Now I want to create a client and server, and use rdma write to continuously write data to the server. How can I implement it. I found some information, but the client is disconnected after writing an operation , and cannot continue to write, for example, like a loop, each cycle sends a write operation.

I hope someone can tell me how to implement it in one connection multiple write operations